# Why my iptables configuration for port-knocking does not work?

Tags: linux, ssh, python, port, iptables

I implemented the following `iptables` rules on my test server for a course.
The firewall shuts down and I cannot access port 22. However, after
knocking on the ports 1111, 2222 and 3333 in that order - the port 22 should be opened.
Nevertheless, my `ssh` is still blocked.

I am knocking to each port through a Python script:

```
# knock_list = [1111, 2222, 3333]

for port in knock_list:
    time.sleep(1.5)

    sock = None
    try:
        print 'Knocking:', ip_address, port
        sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        sock.set_timeout(1)
        sock.connect((ip_address, port))

    except:
        pass

    finally:
        if sock:
            sock.close()
```

**Why my iptables configuration for port-knocking does not work?**

**My iptables configuration**

```
sudo iptables -P INPUT ACCEPT
sudo iptables -P FORWARD ACCEPT
sudo iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT
sudo iptables -F

sudo iptables -N KNOCKING
sudo iptables -N GATE1
sudo iptables -N GATE2
sudo iptables -N GATE3
sudo iptables -N PASSED

sudo iptables -A INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT

sudo iptables -A INPUT -j KNOCKING

sudo iptables -A GATE1 -p tcp --dport 1111 -m recent --name AUTH1 --set -j DROP
sudo iptables -A GATE1 -j DROP

sudo iptables -A GATE2 -m recent --name AUTH1 --remove
sudo iptables -A GATE2 -p tcp --dport 2222 -m recent --name AUTH2 --set -j DROP
sudo iptables -A GATE2 -j GATE1

sudo iptables -A GATE2 -j GATE1

sudo iptables -A GATE3 -m recent --name AUTH2 --remove
sudo iptables -A GATE3 -p tcp --dport 3333 -m recent --name AUTH3 --set -j DROP
sudo iptables -A GATE3 -j GATE1

sudo iptables -A PASSED -m recent --name AUTH3 --remove
sudo iptables -A PASSED -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A PASSED -j GATE1

sudo iptables -A KNOCKING -m recent --rcheck --seconds 30 --name AUTH3 -j PASSED
sudo iptables -A KNOCKING -m recent --rcheck --seconds 10 --name AUTH2 -j GATE3
sudo iptables -A KNOCKING -m recent --rcheck --seconds 10 --name AUTH1 -j GATE2

sudo iptables -A KNOCKING -j GATE1
```

Answer (score 1):

Two things to mention.

Firstly you make a policy (-P) ACCEPT for each of INPUT, OUTPUT and FORWARD. Better you close (DROP) everything, especially on INPUT, and open only what is needed.

Second, I do not know Python very well but usually this kind of connection do not send just one packet, but many more. Even if you do a timeout of 1 second, there will be (I guess) 2 identical packets sent, because there was no answer for the first. So the first packet brings the source in the next list AUTH+1, and the second paket remove it and bring the source back to list AUTH1.

I would advise to rewrite your portknocking taking into account multiple identical packets sent on the same port.